# Outlook: unusual behaviour when opening folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have encountered a very strange problem in Outlook 2013, and am not really sure how to go about diagnosing the issue.

When the user clicks on a folder, Outlook opens the folder but then very quickly switches to some other folder, such as Inbox or Drafts. Doesn't always switch to the same one. The list of folders also seems to shift around a bit/reorder itself when this happens.

There's a lot of subfolders beneath most of the folders... and it's not a consistent problem. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. Seemingly random.

Anyway, I am not so familiar with how the Office suite works, and Outlook in particular. I have tried looking around for this issue but I haven't found anything, it's quite hard to fit it into a google search.

Could anybody help me figure out how to diagnose the issue? Or perhaps somebody has encountered this issue before?

Comment: What kind of mail connection is in question? (IMAP, Exchange, POP3?) If Exchange, is Outlook in Cached mode or not?  If so, have you tried clearing the cache file and letting it rebuild?  Have you tried switching the mode from cached to no cache (or vise versa) to see if the problem goes away?  If it happens frequently enough, try testing it with Outlook in safe mode (`outlook.exe /safe`) and see if it still behaves the same way or not. Also, have you tried changing the mouse batteries? :)

Comment: It's an Exchange connection. I will try those out. Thanks!